# ESP32 won't connect to wifi

Tags: visual-studio, wifi, esp32, platformio

I am working on a project in VS with Platformio and C++ which involves connecting an ESP32 to wifi.  Suddenly my program stopped connecting to my Wifi.  Nothing relevant was altered but suddenly nothing will connect, mystifying!
Current program listed below which just tries to make the connection which compiles uploads and runs fine but doesn't connect in the same way nothing else does!...

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

// put function declarations here:
#define WIFI_SSID "your SSID"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "your password"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID,WIFI_PASSWORD);

  Serial.println("starting");


}
bool isConnected = false;

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
    isConnected = true;

  }
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(1000);
    isConnected = false;

  }
}
```

Compilation up to upload....

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (6.4.0) > DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES:

- framework-arduinoespressif32 @ 3.20011.230801 (2.0.11)
- tool-esptoolpy @ 1.40501.0 (4.5.1)
- tool-mkfatfs @ 2.0.1
- tool-mklittlefs @ 1.203.210628 (2.3)
- tool-mkspiffs @ 2.230.0 (2.30)
- toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch5
  LDF: Library Dependency Finder
  LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
  Found 33 compatible libraries
  Scanning dependencies...
  Dependency Graph
  |-- WiFi @ 2.0.0
  Building in release mode
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/src/main.cpp.o
  Building .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/bootloader.bin
  esptool.py v4.5.1
  Creating esp32 image...
  Merged 1 ELF section
  Successfully created esp32 image.
  Generating partitions .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/partitions.bin
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFi.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiAP.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiGeneric.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiMulti.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiSTA.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiScan.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/WiFi/WiFiUdp.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/Esp.cpp.o
  Archiving .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib00b/libWiFi.a
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/FirmwareMSC.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/FunctionalInterrupt.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/HWCDC.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/IPAddress.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/IPv6Address.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/MD5Builder.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/Print.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/Stream.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/StreamString.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/Tone.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/USB.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/USBCDC.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/USBMSC.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/WMath.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/WString.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/base64.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/cbuf.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-adc.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-bt.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-cpu.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-dac.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-gpio.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-i2c-slave.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-i2c.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-ledc.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-matrix.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-misc.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-psram.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-rgb-led.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-rmt.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-sigmadelta.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-spi.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-time.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-timer.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-tinyusb.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-touch.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/esp32-hal-uart.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/firmware_msc_fat.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/libb64/cdecode.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/libb64/cencode.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/main.cpp.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/stdlib_noniso.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/wiring_pulse.c.o
  Compiling .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/FrameworkArduino/wiring_shift.c.o
  Archiving .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/libFrameworkArduino.a
  Linking .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.elf
  Retrieving maximum program size .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.elf
  Checking size .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.elf
  Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
  RAM:   [=         ]  12.9% (used 42320 bytes from 327680 bytes)
  Flash: [=====     ]  54.5% (used 714193 bytes from 1310720 bytes)
  Building .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.bin
  esptool.py v4.5.1
  Creating esp32 image...
  Merged 25 ELF sections
  Successfully created esp32 image.
  Configuring upload protocol...
  AVAILABLE: cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, espota, esptool, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa
  CURRENT: upload_protocol = esptool
  Looking for upload port...
  Auto-detected: /dev/ttyACM0
  Uploading .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.bin
  esptool.py v4.5.1
  Serial port /dev/ttyACM0
  Connecting....
  Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision v3.0)
  Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
  Crystal is 40MHz
  MAC: b0:a7:32:de:a3:30
  Uploading stub...
  Running stub...
  Stub running...

etc etc etc......

I have tried previous working versions, run them on two different ESP32's pinned earlier versions of ESPidf then explored completely seperate connecting only programs including wifi scanners (it can see the network).  Current 'vehicle' is shown below with listing and compilation.  I have looked at the router log and can't find any error or indication of a problem anywhere after several days exploring everything I can think of.  At a complete loss as to how to proceed, where to look, what to do! Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try another board? If the same software that used to work suddenly no longer works, the issue is usually _not_ the software.

Comment: Yes I had what was an unused new esp32 which I then tried.. to no avail.  I am particularly exasperated as I have no leads as to where to look next... Thanks for your attention

Comment: Really strange. Next tests: Does the Wifi work after all (e.g., can you connect to it with a cell phone)? Is it close enough? Is the password correct?

Comment: Does the wifi you try to connect to operate at 2.4GHz or 5GHz? ESP32 only operate at 2.4GHz. Also try the wifi scan sketch example to see if it could detect the AP.

Comment: The router is working normally without issues with all the other devices in the house. Thhere is no sign of issues.  Naturally I have restarted it to make sure.

Comment: The rwo ESPs I am using are listed as devices that have connected in the past.  I deleted the entry for one to see if having a new 'first time' request would solve it... no change unfortunately.

Comment: Is it worth clearing the ESP flash memory?  although I have been swapping between programe that previously worked fine including the scan program which confirmed sight of the network.

Comment: All of this activity is on 2.4GHz channel 1

Comment: I have since tried to connect to an entirely different router and wifi with the same result... no connection and no indication as to why